# Wiremock match request POST by params

Tags: post, parameters, wiremock

I have a simple POST request sending params using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

Looking in the wiremock [docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) I can't find a way to match the request by the params values, something like the `querystring` match I mean.

Furthermore it seems also impossible to `contains` for the body, nor to match the entire body in clear (just as base64).

Is there a way to match this kind of requests?

Answer (score 9):

Another option that I found was to use `contains` for ***Stubbing*** `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/oauth/token",
    "basicAuthCredentials": {
      ...
    },
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "contains": "username=someuser"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem - I wanted to check the exact parameters , but without patterm magic (so easier to maintain). As a workaround, I created a helper class :

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class WireMockUtil {
    public static String toFormUrlEncoded(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
        if (map == null) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            String value = map.get(key);
            appendFormUrlEncoded(key,value,sb);
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                sb.append('&');
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String toFormUrlEncoded(String key, String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        appendFormUrlEncoded(key, value,sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void appendFormUrlEncoded(String key, String value, StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.append(key).append('=');
        if (value != null) {
            sb.append(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the Wiremock test you can use it via:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");

...

withRequestBody(equalTo(WireMockUtil.toFormUrlEncoded(map))).
```

Or check only dedicated parts by `containing`:

```java
withRequestBody(containing(WireMockUtil.toFormUrlEncoded("key","value1"))).
```

Comment: A problem with this, is that it depends on the exact order of arguments, so may not work for all use cases.

Comment: If this is a problem for your usecases, you could use a tree map instead of the linked hash map - so the ordering is always the same.

Comment: Dont think that would help, as it would still matching on the exact string with `withRequestBody(equalTo(WireMockUtil.toFormUrlEncoded(map)))`

Comment: You are right, the tree map was just an idea and would not solve your issue. 

But my solution does work well in our own wire mock tests where I had the problems mentioned in this Stackoverflow question. To see my usage please look at 
https://github.com/de-jcup/sechub/blob/ae7197110ac226f9f92c46cde815fb902761ab8a/sechub-adapter-checkmarx/src/test/java/com/mercedesbenz/sechub/adapter/checkmarx/CheckmarxAdapterV1WireMockTest.java#L474-L494

Answer (score 3):

With classic wiremock you can use bodyPatterns' matchers and regular expressions:

for example:

```
...
"request": {
   "method": "POST",
   "url": "/api/v1/auth/login",
   "bodyPatterns": [
     {
       "matches": "(.*&|^)username=test($|&.*)"
     },
     {
       "matches": "(.*&|^)password=123($|&.*)"
     }
   ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net

Matching query **parameters** and **body** can be done with this example json:

```
{
    "Guid": "dae02a0d-8a33-46ed-aab0-afbecc8643e3",
    "Request": {
      "Url": "/testabc",
      "Methods": [
        "put"
      ],
      "Params": [
        {
          "Name": "start",
          "Values": [ "1000", "1001" ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "end",
          "Values": [ "42" ]
        }
      ],
       "Body": {
        "Matcher": {
          "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
          "Pattern": "test*test"
        }
      }
    }
}
```